# Where should I start advanced GIS learning

Tags: coordinate-system, references

I am relatively familiar with most of the GIS stuff. I develop GIS applications as well with open source offerings. Still I find some lapses in my theoretical knowledge in GIS.

What resources like books can you propose which might be good for an advanced GIS learner with a touch of software development?

One area I think I am weak in is coordinate systems and the theory behind coordinate systems.